# VSTO: How to identify a drag n drop item as an email attachment?

Tags: email, drag-and-drop, vsto, email-attachments

I have a VSTO add-in which allows users to drag n drop emails to an item in a listbox and save it.  When a user drags an email attachment I would like to be able to save the attachment only and not the entire email.

Current code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= OL.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count; i++)
{
     Object temp = OL.ActiveExplorer().Selection[i];

     if (temp is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
     {
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem = 
         (temp as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem);
```

I have tried using:

```
if (temp is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment) 
if (temp is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments)
```

to trap it with no luck.

Is there any way to figure out if the item dropped is an email attachment?